# What is a good way to generate a large datafile by appending records in R?

Tags: python, r, pytables

When I need to process raw data or generate large amount of synthetic data, I use pytables in Python and loop over each row and "append" the row to a table. So I do not have to know the size of the table ex-ante. For example,

```
import tables

class test(tables.IsDescription):
    col1 = tables.Int32Col()
    col2 = tables.Int32Col()

hdf5_a = tables.openFile('test.hdf5', 'a')

table = hdf5_a.createTable('/', 'test', test)

for i in range(10):
    table.row['col1'] = i
    table.row['col2'] = i * 10

    table.row.append()

table.flush()
hdf5_a.close()
```

I need to do the same thing with R. Basically I want:

1. generate synthetic data
2. append data on the fly to a binary file on the disk
3. later use this data without loading the whole thing to the memory

I seems packages such as `ff` and `bigmemory` should be useful for this, but examples I saw were a bit different from my need. Is there any code snippets which does something like this in R? I think a simple code example will be very helpful.

Comment: There are some fundamental differences between R and Python. In R normally you wouldn't loop over each row and append it. There are usually better alternatives. However, R is designed to hold everything in memory. If that is not possible for you, you should at least work with bigger chunks of the the whole data and not only single rows. Or you stay with Python, since that seems to work for you ...

Comment: How are `ff` and `bigmemory` different from your need? Because these are the first that spring to mind for your question.

Comment: @Roland Not really. In Python I wouldn't loop over each row and append it either - I would use numpy array or recarray, for example. It's just in this specific application I need to do that. Also each row VS each chunk is not an essential issue here, the issue is appending incremental data instead of generating everything at once. Of course - I would love to use Python for this, but I have to use R for this application.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan Sorry, what I meant was the examples I saw were cases where one has a dataset already an a csv file - which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a function for generating some data

```
gendata <- function() {
  n <- 1E3
  data.frame(a = 1:n, b = rnorm(n), c = sample(letters, n, replace=TRUE))
}
```

#### `ff` + `ffbase`

For `ff` the following pattern can be used:

```
library(ffbase)

dat <- NULL
for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  d <- gendata()
  dat <- ffdfappend(dat, d)
}
save.ffdf(dat, dir="./test")
```

The data can be loaded again by using `load.ffdf("./test")`.

#### CSV

For test/csv files the following pattern can be used:

```
con <- file("test.csv", "wt")
first_block <- TRUE
for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  d <- gendata()
  write.table(d, file=con, sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=first_block)
  first_block <- FALSE
}
close(con)
```

To use it, you will first have to import it into `ff` or `bigmemory`, or you can use it (read only) using `LaF`.

Answer (score 1):

The approach would be the same in R -- open a file for writing, append chunks, close the file. If you're familiar with HDF5 then [rhdf5](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html) is one option. The package [vignette](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html) includes in section 3.3 an explicit example of iteration to create the file. The key is to doing this efficiently is write in chunks -- multiple rows to make use of R's efficient vectoriation -- rather than single line at a time. But you could also write single line at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the ansewr, but I wanted a sample code snippet.